# NSLogv C strings encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote a small logging wrapper using `NSLogv`:

```
void MyLog(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, format);
    NSString* formatStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:format];
    NSLogv(formatStr, vargs);
    va_end(vargs);
}
```

which I can use like that:

```
MyLog("%d - %s", 123, "ABCD");
```

The problem I have is when I use characters outside the standard ASCII range:

```
MyLog("%d - %s", 123, "АБВГ");
```

`NSLogv` fails to properly encode those characters:

```
2019-10-01 11:10:30.890346+0300 TestApp[86349:7051788] 123 - –ê–ë–í–ì
```

What would be the proper way to encode such characters while maintaining the variadic signature of my helper method?

P.S. Tried on both `X86_64` simulator and `ARM64` device

If I convert the C strings to UTF16, then it works as expected:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
std::u16string value16 = convert.from_bytes("АБВГ");
MyLog("%d - %S", 123, value16.c_str());
```

Comment: Is that string UTF-8 encoded?  (which will depend on the encoding of the source files)

Comment: Well, I suppose yes, because if I write `NSLog(@"%d - %s", 123, "АБВГ");`, then everything prints out correctly. Also if I read the variadic parameters and convert them to `NSString` it works. But I was hoping there was a more generic way of doing it, without looping through the variadic arguments and casting them to some types.

Comment: I think you should log: `MyLog("%d - %@", 123, @"АБВГ");`

Comment: This looks like encoding issue. In some step you have inconsistent encoding. Make sure compiler uses same encoding as your source code (editor). Try setup global c-locale to system locale: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered a curious "feature" of formatting in Objective-C and should visit [Apple's Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) and report it.

So what is going on? Well it is nothing to do with variadic functions at all, and nothing to do with `NSLogv` *per se*. Rather it is to do with the underlying Objective-C formatting code which `NSLog`, `NSLogv`, `stringWithFormat:`, *et al* use and the *type* of the format string itself...

Here is a simple demonstration of the "feature":

```
- (void)demo
{
   char *sample = "АБВГ"; // This will be UTF-8 encoded

   // use %p to show address, %s to show string, \n as printf doesn't add one
   char *cFormat = "%p - %s\n";
   NSString *nsFormat = @"%p - %s\n"; // produces an __NSCFConstantString
   NSString *convertedFormat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cFormat]; // produces an __NSCFString

   printf(cFormat, sample, sample); // works
   NSLog(convertedFormat, sample, sample); // fails with __NSCFString
   NSLog(nsFormat, sample, sample); // works with __NSCFConstantString

   NSLog(@"formats equal: %s", [convertedFormat isEqualToString:nsFormat] ? "yes" : "no"); // __NSCFString & __NSCFConstantString are equal
}
```

Run that and the console will show something like:

```
0x1000013f8 - АБВГ
2019-10-01 10:25:48.222537+0100 demo[8435:1431874] 0x1000013f8 - –ê–ë–í–ì

2019-10-01 10:25:48.222560+0100 demo[8435:1431874] 0x1000013f8 - АБВГ
2019-10-01 10:25:48.222582+0100 demo[8435:1431874] formats equal: yes
```

So the C library `printf` works, `NSLog` with a *constant* `NSString` format works, but `NSLog` with `NSString` format converted from a `char *` does not, and yet the latter two formats compare equal... Notice also that in the failing case `NSLog` adds an extra newline.

The bad output, `–ê–ë–í–ì`, is the same interpretation of the argument string that Xcode shows for the string's memory bytes. So the underlying type of the *format* string is determining how the underlying bytes of the *argument* string are interpreted...

Such a curious "feature" makes one wonder whether it was *designed* for some reason, or whether we're missing the obvious... Maybe someone else can enlighten us, but unless they do let's call this a (curious) bug!

**Workaround**

As the above demo shows using the C library format functions work so if you are happy with losing `NSLog`'s preamble on each outline you can just use one of them in your function:

```
void MyLog(const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list vargs;
   va_start(vargs, format);
   vprintf(format, vargs);
   va_end(vargs);
}
```

If you wish to keep to `NSLog` for the output you can use one of the C library's equivalents of `stringWithFormat:`, here is a version of your function which dynamically allocates the required space for the formatted C string and then free's it (ARC won't do that for you!):

```
void MyLog(const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list vargs;
   va_start(vargs, format);
   char *output;
   vasprintf(&output, format, vargs);
   NSLog(@"%s", output);
   free(output);
   va_end(vargs);
}
```

The "feature" still exists with the latest Xcode 11 and macOS Catalina Beta so please do go report it at [Apple's Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).

HTH

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

Look's like bug in `NSLogv` function, because `NSLog`, `printf`, `vprintf` works fine.
I can suggest use macro instead:

```
#define MyLog(arg, ...) NSLog(@ arg, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: This seems to work but do you know how can I invoke this macro from my custom function? The problem I have with this approach is that I cannot declare this macro inside a header file because I need to be able to use this header from both `.cpp` and `.mm` files. Inside the header file I need to have a generic variadic function that can be used from both pure C++ and Objective C files and thus including Foundation classes is not an option.